# Не работает сортировка объекта по ключам

Tags: javascript, сортировка, объекты

Есть объект:

```
var list = { 
0.11283492347: {asd: 12, field: 10}, 
0.228929: {asd: 9, field: 2}, 
0.332783728: {asd: 7, field: 6}, 
0.4421231: {asd: 14, field: 8} 
};
```

Надо отсортировать его (расположить ключи) в порядке уменьшение (или увеличения) значения поля field

Вот код - но ни чего не работает. В чем дело?

```
function sortObject(list, field){ 
            var sortable = []; 

            for(var key in list){ 
                if(list.hasOwnProperty(key)){ 
                    sortable.push([key, list[key]]); 
                } 
            } 

            function ASB(a, b) { 
              if ( a[field] > b[field] ) { 
                return 1; 
              } else if (b[field] < a[field]) {   
                return -1; 
              } else { 
                return 0; 
              } 
            } //function 

             sortable.sort(ASB);

            var orderedList = {}; 

            for(var i = 0; i < sortable.length; i ++){ 
                orderedList[sortable[i][0]] = sortable[i][1]; 
            } 

            return orderedList; 
        } 

sortObject(list, 'field');

console.log('arr', sortObject(list, 'field'));
```

Вот что должно получиться (хотелось бы увидеть в итоге):

```
orderedList = { 
    0.228929: {asd: 9, field: 2}, 
    0.332783728: {asd: 7, field: 6},  
    0.4421231: {asd: 14, field: 8}, 
    0.11283492347: {asd: 12, field: 10},
    };
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript не гарантирует порядок полей в объектах.

Из спецификации ECMAScript 3

> #### 4.3.3 Object
>
> An object is a member of the type Object. **It is an unordered collection of properties** each of which contains a primitive value, object, or function. A function stored in a property of an object is called a method.

Из более свежей ECMAScript 9

> #### 13.7.5.15 EnumerateObjectProperties ( O )
>
> When the abstract operation EnumerateObjectProperties is called with argument
>   O, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Assert: Type(O) is Object.
> 2. Return an Iterator object (25.1.1.2) whose next method iterates over all the String-valued keys of enumerable properties of O. The
>      iterator object is never directly accessible to ECMAScript code. **The
>      mechanics and order of enumerating the properties is not specified**
>      but must conform to the rules specified below.

Comment: Что же делать? Мне нужно по ключам хранить множество объектов и обращаться к ним по ключам. Но важен порядок этих ключей для дальнейшей отрисовки игроков (то есть порядок ключей сортируется по одному из параметров).

Comment: @Aleksandr используйте websql :)

Comment: @Aleksandr самое элементарное решение - хранить дополнительный ключ типа `key_order: [0.228929, 0.332783728, 0.4421231, 0.11283492347]` и учитывать его при доступе.

Comment: Не понял вашего ответа - можно уточнить на моем простом примере выше ) (написать для примера выше)

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, 6 уже не совсем свежая :-)

Comment: @Grundy исправил :)